# EXC_BAD_EXCESS in Objective C when function uses getter

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, exc-bad-access

```
- (NSDictionary *)myPropertyList   //Calling getter of myPropertyList
{
    if(!_myPropertyList){
        NSArray *colorsUsed = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
        _myPropertyList=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: colorsUsed, @"colorUsed",[NSNumber numberWithDouble:MAX_RADIUS],@"maximumRadius",[NSNumber numberWithDouble:MIN_RADIUS],@"minimumRadius", [NSNumber numberWithInt:20],@"circleNumbers", nil];;
    }
    return _myPropertyList;
}

- (NSArray *)generateCircleList
{
    int minRadius=[[self.myPropertyList objectForKey:@"minimumRadius"] intValue];
    int maxRadius=[[self.myPropertyList objectForKey:@"maximumRadius"] intValue];
    ...
    //code continues
```

I have this piece of code in my model. When the function generateCircleLlist is called that uses the myPropertyList, it is crashing with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I really looked around but couldn't find a solution to this. Any help?

Comment: You have a dictionary containing a set of properties... but why not make them actual properties of the class (or another class)?

Comment: Hmm that's a good idea actually. I'll try that too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are creating colorsUsed but using colorUsed, also add [colorsUsed release]; for memory management.

```
if(!_myPropertyList){

    NSArray *colorsUsed = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
    _myPropertyList=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: colorsUsed, @"colorUsed",[NSNumber numberWithDouble:MAX_RADIUS],@"maximumRadius",[NSNumber numberWithDouble:MIN_RADIUS],@"minimumRadius", [NSNumber numberWithInt:20],@"circleNumbers", nil];

    [colorsUsed release];
}
```